System proxy in windows 10 is getting enabled when turning on the VPN
Whenever I turn my VPN in windows 10 on, the system proxy in which the address is 127.0.0.1:2334 is automatically enabled and I can't connect to the internet.

What VPN are you using? How did you install it? How are you enabling the VPN? You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
